# Editing and Naming a newly added chart in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I am trying to write a macro in Excel VBA that adds a chart and then want to rename it and edit the colors of the columns but somehow it throws a debug error.

Here's my code. Can someone please help me:

```
Sub Charts()

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddCha rt.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked100
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Calculations").Range("A1:D11")
ActiveChart.Name = "MyChart"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Data!$N$5:$N$14"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Select
    ActiveChart.Legend.Select
    ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries(1).Select
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    With Selection.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
    ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries(2).Select
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    With Selection.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
    ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries(3).Select
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    With Selection.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
    Selection.Delete
    End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Which row is producing the error, and what exactly is the error?

Comment: For this: ActiveChart.Name = "MyChart", the error is: The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type.

Comment: For this: With Selection.Format.Fill, the error is Method 'Fill' of object 'ChartFormat' failed

Comment: oops...there's a space by mistake there. It should be : AddChart.Select. I deleted the space but the error is still there.

Comment: Yes, I found it. :) Anyway, the `Chart.Name` property is read only for chart objects (embedded charts), you can't assign a value to it. Give me one minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the .Name property can only be set for Chart Sheets. For Embedded charts (chart objects) it is read only, so you can't assign a value to it. You can assign a value to it's container's name:

```
ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "MyChart"
```

Instead of trying to format the legend entries, format the series themselves. I have also rewritten your .with statements, there is no need to select each item before formatting them:

```
Sub ChartThingy()

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked100
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Calculations").Range("A1:D11")
ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "MyChart"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Data!$N$5:$N$14"
  With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Format
    With .Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    With .Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
  End With
  With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Format
    With .Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    With .Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
  End With
  With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Format
    With .Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    With .Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
  End With
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
    Selection.Delete
End Sub
```